# Videoplayer in a detached expo project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I am currently developing a mobile app in react-native with the expo library. As expo doesn't support every third party library the project had to be detached from expo.

My problem arised when I tried to add a video player to the project.
I thought that maybe some other library collided with the video player so I made a new clean project with only the video player.

The clean project has the same set-up as the main project, react-native with detached expo.

I followed this guide to detach from expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/expokit/detach/

I followed this guide to set up react-native-unimodels: https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules

I followed this guide to add the video library: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-av

When I try to compile the code in Android studios I get the following error output:[image: compilation error]

My `App.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Video
        source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
        rate={1.0}
        volume={1.0}
        isMuted={false}
        resizeMode="cover"
        shouldPlay
        isLooping
        style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
      />

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

My build.gradle (Module:app): https://pastebin.com/kHTTdUrM

My build.gradle (Project:android): https://pastebin.com/idxF7a8j

MainApplication:

```
public class MainApplication extends ExpoApplication implements AppLoaderPackagesProviderInterface {

  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(Arrays.<Package>asList(
    new ReactAdapterPackage(),
    new ConstantsPackage(),
    new PermissionsPackage(),
    new FileSystemPackage(),
    new AVPackage()
 ), Arrays.<SingletonModule>asList());

  @Override
  public boolean isDebug() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  // Needed for `react-native link`
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
    );
  }

    public List getExpoPackages() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new CameraPackage(),
                new ConstantsPackage(),
                new SensorsPackage(),
                new FileSystemPackage(),
                new FaceDetectorPackage(),
                new GLPackage(),
                new GoogleSignInPackage(),
                new PermissionsPackage(),
                new SMSPackage(),
                new PrintPackage(),
                new ConstantsPackage(),
                new MediaLibraryPackage(),
                new SegmentPackage(),
                new FontLoaderPackage(),
                new LocationPackage(),
                new ContactsPackage(),
                new BarCodeScannerPackage(),
                new AdMobPackage(),
                new LocalAuthenticationPackage(),
                new LocalizationPackage(),
                new AppAuthPackage(),
                new TaskManagerPackage(),
                new BackgroundFetchPackage()
        );
    }

  @Override
  public String gcmSenderId() {
    return getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldUseInternetKernel() {
    return BuildVariantConstants.USE_INTERNET_KERNEL;
  }

  public static OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
    // Customize/override OkHttp client here
    return builder;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

We didn't find any solution to this problem involving expo, what we did was completely remove the expo library and created a new project with only react-native. So far there has been no problem adding all the libraries needed for the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `video module` without detached it.

You don't need to do `expo eject`.

Video example.js:

```js
import { Video } from 'expo';
...
<Video
  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
  rate={1.0}
  volume={1.0}
  isMuted={false}
  resizeMode="cover"
  shouldPlay
  isLooping
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```

it is [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/) about Video module

Comment: The main project is detached and can't use this solution.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of projects, why don't you move the files?